# Google Play Music - Edit tags of Remotely Stored Music?

Tags: google-play-music, id3-tag

I am often surprised by the treatment of MP3 names by the native music player, Play Music. Fairly frequently albums are split, or unexpected titles pop up, etc. I am pretty meticulous about ID3s in my collection, and I often can't exactly determine the reason for the unexpected behavior.

Luckily, for those files I copy directly to the phone (Nexus 4), I can fix the issue fairly simply with an app called MP3dit (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ADnet&hl=en). For those that I upload to the cloud via Google Music Manager I am not aware of any such option. Is there a method for changing these? I can't find any alternatives/plugins to Google Music Manager, or at least not yet.

I thought of trying the "Keep on Device" thumbtack button - doing keep, making the edit, and then unkeeping it. However, this is would be tedious and unwieldy, plus I can't seem to find the location of the file once it is downloaded.

One, but far from the only example. Tags looks uniform, but player splits album. And that one funky artist name with all the extra spaces!
[image: Back on the hard drive - looks well tagged and uniform]

[image: From the phone - far from it!]

So...

1 - Is there a way for me to change the artist/track/album info on these cloud-stored songs?

2 - Can anyone shed some light on the naming system in general? I'm fairly certain it isn't simply ID3s. Some albums that look totally uniform on my hard drive are then split when copied to the Nexus 4 (both on device and remotely stored, but at least those on the device are fairly easily fixed)

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess that Unicode had/has a hand in the misrepresentation of the data in those fields when applied as tags to songs.

Comment: You can now access those via the context menu of each track and choose "Edit info". And it even offers suggestions.

Comment: by "now" you mean 5.1, correct?

Answer (score 1):

I would check the 'album artist' and 'composer' tags in addition to the 'artist' tag. I had Google play do some ridiculous things to my music because of those fields. Setting album artist equal to artist, and ensuring composer was blank, fixed my issues.

Answer (score 0):

I use album art changer from playstore to keep my music file tags proper...the reason why they are splitting up are becasue there are some unseen tags which differ ...u can check this through the 'album Art changer' and if that doesnt help u can try mp3tag (it displays all the tags ) for desktop if i am not wrong